# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform

Tags: java, android

I am facing this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class

i searched online to resolve this problem but i could find right solution,so please help with codes

my graddle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.strobilanthes.ftlogistics"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    } }}dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile project(':beacon-keeper-library')
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3'
compile 'me.neavo:volley:2014.12.09'}
```

Comment: some of your libraries are duplicate . Check it in your library projects too