# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug' in android + volley libraries

Tags: android, json, compiler-errors, android-volley

I've read article  [this in backendless](http://support.backendless.com/topic/execution-failed-with-backendless-please-solve-this-problem-quick#comment-12955) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021111/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209631/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithjarmergingfordebug) in StackOverflow. But there isn't any help for me. I searched everywhere but there isn't any solution.The error is bellow

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/VolleyError;

In build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
compile project(":volley")
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
```

}

This error will disappear when removing  `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'` in build.gradle.

What I need to be done is pass the data within app and server(localhost). To pass the string I'm using JSON. In android app using [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) libraries.

What would be I missed? Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the `build.gradle` file, or at least all of its `dependencies`, that is triggering this build error. Also, please explain **in detail** what "the JSON doesn't flow same as before done" means.

Comment: I'm edited my question and thanks for your attention @CommonsWare

Comment: Why do you have both a Volley library module *and* an out of date dependency? Use the official dependency instead of both of those.

Comment: If I'm no bothering you @CommonsWare can you tell me please what are the out of date dependencies and official dependencies?. I'm searching everywhere but there aren't any references. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm searching everywhere but there aren't any references

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) shows that Google's official Volley artifact is available via:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Use that instead of `com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18`, [which was published two years ago](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mcxiaoke.volley/library/1.0.18).

Now, you *also* have `compile project(":volley")`. I do not know why. Use *either* `com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0` *or* `compile project(":volley")`, not both. Unless you have some specific reason for using the library module (e.g., you are forking Volley), I would recommend using the `com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0` artifact.

Comment: Thank you very much @CommonsWare. It worked, you save my 3-year degree. [+1]